# Fresh ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Web Application template Browser Link works but has a 404 error

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, browser-link

The Visual Studio Browser Link feature works without errors in a fresh ASP.NET Web Application, but in a fresh ASP.NET Core Web Application it shows a 404 error in the web browser (although the feature does work).

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application" project with the "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" template
- Start Debugging
- In the web browser, refresh the page and check the developer tools for an error such as:

  > GET
  >   http://localhost:17538/__browserLink/requestData/08d7831fcf4c4a0eb58e6099c16a4883?version=2
  >   404 (Not Found)

Is this only happening on my machine? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.6.6 and the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All NuGet package is 2.0.7.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: This is still occurring for me with ASP.NET Core 2.1-rc1 and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.0-rc1. Anyone else?

Comment: Same issue with ASP.NET Core 2.0.7 and VS 2017 15.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a fresh 2.1 .net core solution requires you to install the browserlink nuget package seperately. Its not contained within the *new* aspnetcore.app metapackage.

Comment: I have this NuGet package installed (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.0-rc1) but it still shows this error.